# Grails. How to handle the 'mixed' methods and variables when using @GrailsCompileStatic

Tags: java, grails, groovy, static-compilation

I'm eager to use the `@GrailsCompileStatic` annotation in many places of my grails 3.1.7 application. But the main problem is that it doesn't take into account that domains, commands and controllers are 'mixed' with additional methods (like `save()` or `validate()`) or variables (like `g`).

I found a workaround for the mentioned methods: I inherit domains and commands from an abstract class that has an empty `save()` method (it's implementation is overriden then by grails but static compilation doesn't fail). Also this abstract class implements `grails.validation.Validateable` trait with `validate()` method implementation.

But is there any better way to enable static compilation without these dirty tricks?

In many controllers I use the `g.createLink()` method. How should I pass `g` variable inside to avoid this during the static compilation?

> Error:(37, 39) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - The variable [g] is
>   undeclared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing what @andi answered, just to add a solution to the `g.createLink()` issue: 
You can inject a `LinkGenerator` bean and use static compilation as desired.

Note: you'll have to inject the dependency like this:

```
LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator
```

And import the class from the package `grails.web.mapping`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, @GrailsCompileStatic already allows you to use methods like save().
In my case, it is only a problem of the groovy eclipse plugin, while grails run-app works fine.

Anyway, since grails 3, methods provided by traits are accessible by "implementing" the trait directly as documented [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/traits.html)

> The traits are compatible with static compilation…​

```
class TestController implements Controller {
        @GrailsCompileStatic
        def index() {
            render "test"
        }
    }
```

g seems to be of type NamespacedTagDispatcher, which uses methodMissing to find the called method at runtime. Even if you would get compile time access to g, g.createLink() wouldn't compile.

You could extract performance critical code into another method and annotate it with @CompileStatic or write an unannotated method that is calling g.createLink()